# Saving output of a loop to file

Tags: python

I want to save the output (0,1,1,2,3) of for-loop to the file but my code writes just the last value (3) of loop. How can I fix it?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
for c in range(0, 5):
   print(fib(c))
   file=open("fib.txt","w")
   s = str(fib(c))
   file.write(s+"\n")
#   file.write("%s\n" % fib(c))
   file.close()
```

Comment: Open the file in append mode: 'file=open("fib.txt","a")

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: When you open the file in writeable mode then it rewrites the contents use append mode instead.

Comment: Put the `open` and the `close` outside the loop.

Comment: I suggest to open the file before the for loop and close the file after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to this.

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
file=open("fib.txt", "a")
for c in range(0, 5):
   print(fib(c))
   s = str(fib(c))
   file.write(s + "\n")
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read about [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and [context managers](http://eigenhombre.com/2013/04/20/introduction-to-context-managers/):

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield a

with open("fib.txt","w") as f:
    for x in fib(5):
        f.write(str(x) + '\n')
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

Well its not only easy but far more easy then easy ... :P

use the same code just change the mode of file while opening that is...

```
file=open("fib.txt","w") #opens your file in write mode
```

so.. change it to

```
file=open("fib.txt","a") #opens your file in append mode
```

which will open your file in append mode.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to `yield` instead of `return`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield a
for c in range(0, 5):
   print(fib(c))
   file=open("fib.txt","w")
   for s in str(fib(c)):
       file.write(s+"\n")
   file.close()
```